# Will php code exit after echo for ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I am running a typical php-engined ajax webpage. I use echo to return a html string from the php code. My question is, if I have some other code after the echo, will those code get executed? Or echo behaves similar to exit, which immediately return and stop running the php code? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, `echo` in no way exits, you normally have more than one echo in a script. [`exit`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) does take a string argument that it will output before exiting, however, so you can do:

```
exit("your string here");
```

and it will output the string and exit

Answer (score 1):

No, echo would not. To exit after echoing things, you'd say

> echo "Dear me, good bye!"; exit();

Answer (score 0):

echo will simply return text to ajax javascript part; however the code after or before echo/echos will execute

Answer (score 0):

No. PHP scripts are rendered in their entirety unless you explicitly exit them. ANY output on a script will be passed back to the ajax function if it was called through ajax.

```
echo 'This gets outputted<br />';
echo 'As does this';
```

Comment: ok but will this fire the ajax callback twice? Or is the entire PHP script executed before both strings will be passed back to the ajax callback?

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a single file and you want your script to exit after performing ajax request with out having to add extra vars to your ajax url or evaluate vars to exit, i would suggest creating a function that performs your ajax, have the function return true on success, then do:

```
if(ajaxFunction($paramOne, $paramTwo)){exit();}
```