# After ajax catch php echo, adds \n to output

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

I have a very simple problem. When ajax catch echo from php witch look like this:

```
<h2> Hello world </h2>
 <p>Simple text</p>
```

the ajax adds \n into it so the out in HTML page looks like this:

> Hello world 
>   \n\n
>   Simple text
>   \n

And it (\n) dissapear after reload. Its not fault of PHP because when i look for \n character before echo, it wont replace anything, so it have to be by ajax processing. Dont you know what to do to get rid of \n in output without reloading page?

**EDIT:**
ajax: ... I made it simple...

```
$('#send').click(function(){
  var obsah = CKEDITOR.instances['content'].getData();
  var id = adr();
  $.ajax({
    data:{'content': content, 'id':id},
    success: function(data){
          $('#removeable').append(data);           
       },
    error: function(){
        alert('Error')    
      }
    });
  });
```

php:

```
if(!empty($_POST['content'])){
    $prispevek = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $sql = "UPDATE navigation SET `content` = CONCAT_WS('',`content`,'$prispevek') WHERE `ID` = '$id'";
    mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    //$prispevek = str_replace("\n", "", $prispevek);
    echo $prispevek;
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell what's happening here, can we see code? both php and js

Comment: Are you sure that your php doesn't have an empty line after the end of the file?

Comment: If it would, why doesnt str_replace function solve it?

Comment: What about using a trim() function?

Comment: So eventually doesnt work. It was a one time succes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that `\n` (newline) between elements is caused by textarea. So with jQuery its easily fixed  adding line:

```
obsah = obsah.replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use **nl2br** php function? (http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

I think this should help you.

```
echo nl2br($prispevek);
```

And one more thing. I recommend you to add **exit;** or **die();** after you print your php response.

Like this:

```
echo nl2br($prispevek);
exit;
```

Why you should do that? Read this: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909475/will-php-code-exit-after-echo-for-ajax`